# Not working when we host the MVC application as a sub application into IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, routes

We have created the ASP.Net MVC application and hosted as root application and it is working fine.

If we have hosted as a sub application in IIS, the hard coded anchor tags and form actions will be directing the root application alone.

For example

```
<a href="/admin/login">Login here</a>
```

Is there any chance to make the url's should directing the sub application?

Thanks,
Anderson

Answer (score 0):

@sam anderson, Can you use razor for this?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Login here", "Login","Admin")
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Actually we have already implemented this in many places and we have also implemented the url redirection from stand alone js file as follows **window.location.href="/home"**. How can we apply to stand alone js files, since the Html helpers does not working into js files. Do we have any option from server side.